# What is GDB's "here"?

Tags: gdb, inline-assembly, disassembly

I am trying to troubleshoot a bus error with some inline SSE2 assembly. The source code has a macro that uses 5 pointers, and I suspect one of them is not aligned.

I set a breakpoint on the source line. But when I perform a `disass`, it disassembles from the top of the function, and not where the debugger is stopped. There are hundreds of lines of assembly, so its not really helpful to me. Pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> 30 to 40 times in response to "Press ENTER to continue" got old very quickly.

I tried a `disass $pc`, but it dsassembled from the top of the function. I also tried a `disass .` (with the dot meaning "here"), but that resulted in:

```
A syntax error in expression, near `.'.
```

What does GDB use to denote "here"?

Answer (score 0):

You were correct with the use of `$pc` to represent the current location.  The reason that this did not do what you expected when used with the `disassemble` command is that the `disassemble` command tries by default to disassemble the function containing the given address which is what you are seeing.

There are alternative forms that can be given to disassemble, for example `start,end` where `start` and `end` are addresses, or `start,+length` where `start` is an address and `length` is a number of bytes.

Try `help disassemble` at the gdb prompt for more information.

As an alternative you can also use the `x` (examine) command to display instructions, without the smart find the beginning of the function behaviour, so `x/10i $pc` will display 10 instructions starting from `$pc`.  This can be helpful if you only want the instructions disassembled, however you don't have access to the `/m` or `/r` modifiers that are available on the `disassemble` command.  These modifiers display interleaved source and assembler (for `/m`) or the raw instruction bytes (for `/r`).

Also, if the whole press ENTER to continue thing is getting old then you can try `set height 0` to turn off the pager, do make sure that you have enough scroll back in your terminal though :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Yeah, I've read the man page too. But the question is, *"What does GDB use to denote "here"?"* If GDB does not have a notion of "here" (like, say, WindDBG), then state it and tell me its not possible to disassemble at the point where the debugger is stopped.

Comment: OK, I've extended the answer to address specifically your point.